# Arquivo de expansão parou de funcionar quando atualizou versão do APK

Tags: android, google-play

Recentemente atualizei um APK e escolhi a opção para reutilizar o arquivo de expansão (esse arquivo contém vídeos).

Versão antiga

```
1(1.0.0) -> main.1.br.com.myapp.obb
```

Nova versão

```
2(1.0.1) -> selecionei o mesmo
```

Depois de propagar na loja (Google Play), a aplicação atualizou normalmente, baixou e reconheceu o OBB. Mas quando vou reproduzir o vídeo, a aplicação finaliza com o erro abaixo:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12752): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(12752): at com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.APEZProvider.openAssetFile(APEZProvider.java:182)
```

**Atualização**

Adicionei parte dos arquivos para ajudar a identificar o erro.

*ProviderVideoZipUri.java*

```
public class ProviderVideoZipUri extends APEZProvider {
  @Override
  public String getAuthority(){
    return "br.com.appname.provider.ProviderVideoZipUri";
  }
}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<provider
    android:name="br.com.appname.provider.ProviderVideoZipUri"
    android:authorities="br.com.appname.provider.ProviderVideoZipUri"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Alguém ja passou por esse problema?

Muito obrigado

Comment: Esta colocando a versão do apk e do patch como `meta-data` (`mainVersion` e `patchVersion`) na declaração do seu `APEZProvider`?

Comment: Eu não encontrei onde configuro o (mainVersion e patchVersion) no APEZProvider. Eu possuo uma classe "ProviderVideoZipUri" que herda APEZProvider. Nas rotinas de download eu configuro a versão. Interessante que alterando a versão para 3, renomeando o OBB para "main.3.br.com.myapp.obb" e fazendo o upload desse novo OBB na loja, funcionou. Não queria precisar alterar o OBB a cada atualização do APK. Obrigado!

Comment: A configuração é no manifest, dentro da tag `provider`. Na verdade vc só trocaria um ou outro. Se atualizou a versão do apk, troca o `mainVersion`, se atualizou a expansão troca o `patchVersion`.

Comment: Se entendi direito, estou declarando o "provider" sem essa TAG. Atualizei a pergunta com partes do código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como muita coisa na plataforma Android, ainda mais relacionada com o google não é sempre bem documentado, a declaração do `<provider>` de expansion recebe dois parâmetros. Que são usados nesse caso em especial, onde a versão do **APK** não é igual a versão da **Extension**.

Como falei nos comentários, precisa colocar tags `<meta-data>` para informar as versões.

```
<provider
    android:name="br.com.appname.provider.ProviderVideoZipUri"
    android:authorities="br.com.appname.provider.ProviderVideoZipUri"
    android:exported="false">

    <meta-data android:name="mainVersion" android:value="1"></meta-data>
    <meta-data android:name="patchVersion" android:value="2"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

Sempre que atualizar o **APK** deve colocar o `mainVersion` e o `patchVersion` que queria usar (a que fez upload). Senão ele irá assumir o `mainVersion` e o `patchVersion` sendo o `versionCode` do seu apk.

No caso da próxima atualização, terá `mainVersion = 1` e `patchVersion = 1`.

Obs: No código fonte do `APEZProvider`, ele usa essas duas `meta-data`.

O trecho do código é:

```
int patchFileVersion;
int mainFileVersion;
int appVersionCode = packInfo.versionCode;
String[] resourceFiles = null;
if ( null != pi.metaData ) {
    mainFileVersion = pi.metaData.getInt("mainVersion", appVersionCode);
    patchFileVersion = pi.metaData.getInt("patchVersion", appVersionCode);
    String mainFileName = pi.metaData.getString("mainFilename", NO_FILE);
    if ( NO_FILE != mainFileName ) {
        String patchFileName = pi.metaData.getString("patchFilename", NO_FILE);
        if ( NO_FILE != patchFileName ) {
            resourceFiles = new String[] { mainFileName, patchFileName };
        } else {
            resourceFiles = new String[] { mainFileName };
        }
    }
} else {
    mainFileVersion = patchFileVersion = appVersionCode;
}
```

De fato se você não declara o `meta-data`, ele faz o `else` que seta `mainFileVersion = patchFileVersion = appVersionCode`. Que gera o problema.

O restante do código está disponível [aqui](http://my.fit.edu/~vkepuska/ece5570/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/zip_file/src/src/com/android/vending/expansion/zipfile/APEZProvider.java), como não sei a validade do link, fiz uma cópia em um [GIST](https://gist.github.com/wakim/865ab6bcbc551971a5d9).

**Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051213/accessing-apk-expansion-file-with-uri-with-google-zip-expansion-library-causes**

Comment: Perfeito !!! Se um dia precisar alterar o OBB ele vai para "main.4.br.com.myapp.obb" independente do VersionCode. Pelo que entendi, não é necessário declarar o meta-data do patchVersion (se eu não o utilizo), correto? Muito obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: Isso, o `patchVersion` não precisa se você não usa. No seu caso, atualize apenas a `mainVersion` para bater com o valor que você colocou no primeiro `obb`. Assim você não precisa fazer upload denovo.

Comment: OK, muito obrigado.