# Problemas ao ler arquivo de EXPANSION FILE

Tags: android, android-assets

Preciso ler arquivos de um EXPANSION FILE.

No primeiro Log no qual imprimo expansionFile está funcionando perfeitamente, ou seja consegui ler o zip file, mas ao tentar acessar os arquivos de dentro do zip conforme orienta a documentação http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html o arquivo retorna null

```
    ZipResourceFile expansionFile = null;

    try {
        expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(context,
                2, 1);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("DEBUG", expansionFile + "expansionFile");

    AssetFileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("enterprise/config.json");
    Log.d("DEBUG", fd + "FILE");
```

O Arquivo zip tem as seguintes organização

```
 /enterprie

     /0

     /config.json
```

Alguém sabe o problema?

Comment: Igor, dê uma olhada nessa pergunta e na minha resposta para ver se ajuda no seu problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31107/6436

Comment: Não entendi o uso da classe ProviderVideoZipUri na question

Comment: Na verdade eu suspeito que possa ser um problema nas versões da extensão (mainVersion e patchVersion) e do apk. Se elas forem diferente e você não especificar corretamente, ele não vai achar a extensão e vai retornar null.

Comment: A extenção já foi achada, no Log aparece, mas quando tento acessar os arquivos do ZIP que dá null

Comment: Achei que o problema seria o caminho, mas já tentei um monte de coisa e não funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu troquei isso

```
AssetFileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("enterprise/config.json");
```

por isso

```
InputStream is = expansionFile.getInputStream("enterprise/config.json");
```

e funcionou!